# How to assign string to variable with for_loop?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a sidebar ul/li that gets populated with a {% for %} loop. As the for loop runs, I'm using a {% cycle %} to assign each li a certain class that will give it 1 of 5 background colors. This works well.

However, I want to extend this class assignment beyond the li in the sidebar and onto objects that exist on the corresponding product page as well. I'm assuming this would involve assigning some type of variable(s) that I can call elsewhere on the page.

Here's an example:

Cars
Motorcycles
Trucks
Airplanes
Trains

Let's say that Motorcycles is selected. That particular sidebar li got assigned a class of "red" and shows up in the sidebar in a red color.

I'd like to dynamically load that same "red" class into different elements in the content of the Motorcycles page.

I tried adding a variable into the for loop but can't see how this variable would be interpreted elsewhere.

---

In the sidebar snippet:

```
{% for sidebar in sidebar_link %}
    {% assign colorvariable = "{% cycle 'purple', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green' %}" %}
    <a href="{{ sidebar.url }}"><li class="{% cycle 'purple', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green' %}">{{ sidebar.title }}</li></a>
{% endfor %}
```

(This code works before I add the {% assign %}.)

Is there some proper way to do this? Note: this is for a Shopify site where the sidebar.titles match the page.titles, if that allows any possibilities here.

Answer (score 0):

`cycle` is an output tag that cant be used in an `assign` tag. But you can use `capture` and then use you variable :

```
{% for sidebar in sidebar_link %}
  {% capture colorvariable %}{% cycle 'purple', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green' %}{% endcapture %}
  <a href="{{ sidebar.url }}"><li class="colorvariable">{{ sidebar.title }}</li></a>
{% endfor %}
```